# MongoNetworkError on mongoDB connection through Node.Js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to Node.Js and learning through tutorials, I have already installed the mongoDB server and mongoDB compass. Trying to run it with Visual Studio code and windows powershell - but I couldn't connect app to mongoDB.

**code:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/playground').then(()=>
console.log('connected to mongodb..'))
.catch(err => console.error('could not connect to MongoDB..', err));
```

**Error:**

```
could not connect to MongoDB.. MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1128:14) {
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017',
  stack: 'Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017\n' +
    '    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1128:14)'
}]
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi please show a short code example so we can see what you're trying.

Comment: A lot of missing info on this. Please refrase. State you platform, language and versions.

Comment: Please don't paste images, use formatted text.

Comment: @Soviut edited as per suggestion

Comment: @MerakMarey only imported mongoose@5.0.1 in the code

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing the port number. An example of connection string would be `mongodb://localhost:27017/MyDb`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Node.js or MongoDB.

However, the error message looks common to me. It seems that `localhost` refuses the connection on port 27017. So the first thing I would check is if the DB server really is listening on that port.

I even don't know whether your stack runs under Windows or under Linux. But both of them have a tool called `netstat` which you can use to check who is listening on port 27017. If nobody listens there, you know that your DB server did not start as intended.

Another reason for the malfunction could be a firewall which blocks inbound connections to port 27017. This is unlikely in your case, though, because the connection to be established is from `localhost` to `localhost`; such connections usually are not blocked by firewalls.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows and install mongoDB to C drive then you should create two
directory in C drive 
one is "data" and 
inside data create "db" like C://data/db

open your cmd panel and type `mongod -dbpath c://data/db`
and your mongodb service is running and now you able to connect mongoDB